# installing header file

Tags: 12.04, opengl

I have downloaded GLUI 2.35 from http://glui.sourceforge.net/ to my desktop as zip file. But, What should I do in order to use GLUI in the code as shown below ;

```
   #include < GL/glui.h >
```

How can I do that in ubuntu 12.04 ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, instead, you do:

```
    sudo apt-get install libglui2c2 libglui-dev
```

These are version 2.36 and built for Ubuntu.

Comment: But I do not have any internet connection to my home machine.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libglui2c2

Comment: can I install from zip file since I download as zip file?

Answer (score 0):

Please go here http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libglui2c2 and here http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libglui-dev. Download the .deb packages to another computer, as well as the dependencies (red dots) and transfer to your Ubuntu machine. Install all the packages with: sudo dpkg -i *.deb. If you could compile the package you linked, which I doubt highly, since it appears to be built in 2005 (!!), it would require most of these dependencies and many more.

Comment: can I run `sudo apt-get install <file from desktop> <file from desktop>`  to install from desktop

Comment: No. You will be downoading .deb files. They are installed with sudo dpkg -i Desktop/*.deb. The wildcard * means install _all_ the debs.

Answer (score 0):

Get the deb files:

https://debian.pkgs.org/7/debian-main-amd64/libglui2c2_2.36-4_amd64.deb.html and
 https://debian.pkgs.org/7/debian-main-amd64/libglui-dev_2.36-4_amd64.deb.html

Then use the package manager to install

```
sudo dpkg -i libglui2c2_2.36-4_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libglui-dev_2.36-4_amd64.deb
```